# I tried to use bootstrap modal class to make a popup signup form but popup doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I tried to use bootstrap modal class to make a popup signup form and when i press the signup button window just fade and reload that's it. popup doesn't work. I'm using bootstrap 3.3.6. please help.

this is the sign up button code:

```
<form class="navbar-form navbar-right">
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default navbar-btn sign" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#signupForm">Sign up</button>
</form>
```

I am using the signup button inside a nav (navbar-inverse).

this is the popup form code:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="signupForm" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="">
          <span>&times;</span>
        </button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Sign Up</h4>
      </div>

      <div class="modal-body">
        <form class="form-horizontal">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-1">User Name :</label>
            <div class="col-md-5">
              <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm">
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-1">Email :</label>
            <div class="col-md-5">
              <input type="email" class="form-control input-sm">
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-1">Password :</label>
            <div class="col-md-5">
              <input type="password" class="form-control input-sm">
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-1">Confirm Password :</label>
            <div class="col-md-5">
              <input type="password" class="form-control input-sm">
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-8">
              <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="submit">
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I coded this popup form code below the signup button code and that means it's inside the navbar

Comment: It seems to work just fine. Maybe include a bit more of your code?
http://www.bootply.com/GpBdvpW8Hz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check this:

I have created a JS Fiddle and it is working fine here.

```
   ----  https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/19115/
```

You must include Bootstrap js and css file to your project in order to make it work.

Comment: I tried your code and like i said before it didn't work and i put data-backdrop false to this <div class="modal fade" id="signupForm" role="dialog"  data-backdrop="false"> and form popup worked but it vanished automatically

Answer (score 0):

Here your working code

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

</head>

<body>
  <form class="navbar-form navbar-right">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default navbar-btn sign" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#signupForm">Sign up</button>
  </form>

  <div class="modal fade" id="signupForm" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="">
            <span>&times;</span>
          </button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Sign Up</h4>
        </div>

        <div class="modal-body">
          <form class="form-horizontal">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-1">User Name :</label>
              <div class="col-md-5">
                <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm">
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-1">Email :</label>
              <div class="col-md-5">
                <input type="email" class="form-control input-sm">
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-1">Password :</label>
              <div class="col-md-5">
                <input type="password" class="form-control input-sm">
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-1">Confirm Password :</label>
              <div class="col-md-5">
                <input type="password" class="form-control input-sm">
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-8">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="submit">
              </div>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: It still doesn't work i wonder why code seems to be fine. I'll add the full code

Comment: You can run that code snippet and see how it's works. Do you added Jquery?@Kasun

Comment: @DINIDU yes I run it and added to my original file. yes I added jquery also but still no effect

Comment: @Kasun do you added any other scripts with this?if it, then remove them and try again

Comment: I added the code that you wrote to a new pure html file to see whether it's working in that way. It didn't work. It's the same problem background faded and reload the page. I think problem is on my computer

Comment: I added data-backdrop false to this <div class="modal fade" id="signupForm" role="dialog" data-backdrop="false"> and form popup worked but it vanishes

Comment: @Kasun Ensure you dont have lots of jquery referenced in the same page. Many jquery refference could make the popup get confused and then refuse to work. try to remove redundant jquery links

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem. I find out the cause is that button type should be `button` not `submit`. I changed the button type to `button` then it worked.